# AngularJS: RangeError when recursively calling function with $timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to learn AngularJS from the book 'AngularJS from novice to ninja'. (I have programmed before, but not with javascript.)

One example wants to demonstrate events. It uses a recursive call of a function with a timeout. When I try this code out, it gives a RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. Everything works without the recursive call. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks, Pieter

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);

angular.module('myApp.controllers').controller('MessageController', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.messages = [{
        sender: 'user1',
        text: 'Message1'
  }];
  var timer;
  var count = 1;
  $scope.loadMessages = function() {
    ++count;
    $scope.messages.push({
        sender: 'user1',
        text: 'Message'+count
    });
// This line seems to cause the problem
    timer = $timeout($scope.loadMessages(), 2000);
    if (count==3) {
        $scope.$broadcast('EVENT_NO_DATA', 'Not Connected');
        $timeout.cancel(timer);
    }
  };
  timer = $timeout($scope.loadMessages(), 2000);
  $scope.$on('EVENT_RECEIVED', function(){
    console.log('Received emitted event EVENT_RECEIVED in MessageController.');
});
```

});

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers').controller('StatusController', function($scope) {
$scope.name = 'World';
$scope.status = 'Connected';
$scope.statusColor = 'green';
$scope.$on('EVENT_NO_DATA', function(event, data) {
    console.log('Received broadcast event EVENT_NO_DATA in StatusController.');
    $scope.status = data;
    $scope.statusColor = 'red';
    $scope.$emit('EVENT_RECEIVED');
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$scope.loadMessages()` to `$scope.loadMessages`.